# Error while moving a file (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby

I face the error when I try to move one file from another.
I'm sure that path is correct. The platform is windows. Permission is correct.

My code is below:

```
  unless File.exists?(f2)
    FileUtils.move(f1,f2)
  end
```

Note I don't face problem with every file.

Comment: Well, you're checking for f2 (presumably so you don't overwrite it), but is the error that f1 doesn't exist? Be careful when you say "I'm sure that" so and so is correct. Something is happening, and you can get yourself stuck if you assume too much. (You may be right here, but you know what I mean.)

Answer (score 1):

```
FileUtils.move(f1,f2) rescue do
    not File.exists?(f1) and raise "source file does not exist"
    File.exists?(f2) and raise "destination file already exists"
end
```

question should be closable now